# open hyperlinks in new window from swf

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

The swf files  has many hyperlinks.And this swf files are downloaded from an external source .so cannot change its source code.My question is that from javascript,jquery be made that all the hyperlinks that appear in the swf be open in a different window also which starts with an http:// location

```
 <div align="center"><OBJECT classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"  id="myMovieName">

  <PARAM NAME="movie" VALUE="/media/cam.swf" /> <PARAM NAME="quality" VALUE="high" /> <PARAM NAME="bgcolor" VALUE="#FFFFFF" /> <EMBED href="/media/players/camera.swf" src="/media/players/camera.swf" quality=high bgcolor=#FFFFFF NAME="myMovieName" ALIGN="" TYPE="application/x-shockwave-flash"> </EMBED> </OBJECT></div>
```

Comment: sure, and jQuery can make coffee too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the links inside the swf are not opened via ExternalInterface, you can't manipulate the behaviour from the outside via Javascript/jQuery at all.
This being an swf loaded from a remote site it is very likely getUrl, navigateToURL or something similar is used to navigate to new links.

Answer (score 0):

to open a link from your SWF in a new window you can use ;

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://someURL.com"),"_blank");
```

Comment: How would i find out that these hyperlinks are from the swf file and where would i add this?

Comment: Also i need to do this from or javascript